# Using jQuery to obtain option value and apply discount?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sanitize

I need to write a jQuery / Java function that will take the numbers from an AJAX updated value, sanitize it to remove the $, reduce the price by a certain percentage (discPerc) and then make an alert window that notifies the customer of the reduced price.

Here's what I have so far, I realize I'm not the best coder!

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function superSalePrice(discPerc) {
      var optionPrice = $("#productTotal").val();
  var applyDisc = optionPrice * discPerc;
  var rPrice = Math.round(applyDisc * 1) / 1;

  $("tB").click(function() {
  alert("With selected options, final price with discounts is $" + rPrice + "!");
  };
  )
};
</script>
</head>

//THEN the button
<input type="button" id="tB" value="Test Disc. Calc." onclick="superSalePrice(.85);" />

//THEN the option
<td id="productTotal" class="rowElement3"> $3,450.00</td>
```

I don't know how to sanitize the value, so that part has not been included yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make a few changes, try something like this:

```
function superSalePrice(discPerc) {
    var optionPrice = $("#productTotal").html(); // Changed from .val()
    var total = parseFloat(optionPrice.replace(/\$/g, "").replace(/,/g, ""));  // Added this
    var applyDisc = optionPrice * discPerc;
    var rPrice = Math.round(applyDisc * 1) / 1;  // Didn't check this

    // I'm not sure what the following is for, because you are just binding ANOTHER function every time the button is clicked. Maybe you just want the "alert" line
    $("tB").click(function() {
        alert("With selected options, final price with discounts is $" + rPrice + "!");
    });
}
```

Read the comments!

Comment: OMG YOU ARE MY HERO! What is your paypal? Can I say thanks with money?

Comment: Haha absolutely not! I'm glad I helped though. Definitely look at @Blender solution too, as they point out a lot of good things you could use too...for example the sanitization, and overall organization of things!

Comment: Thank you so much! You've just saved what's left of my weekend!

Comment: And you may want to look into used the `toFixed` method that converts a number to string and only keeps the specified decimal places (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). So do all of your number calculations, and at the last moment, use `toFixed` to convert to string with 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

To sanitize your number, just remove everything that isn't a digit or a dot with regex:

```
>'   $3,450.00 '.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
'3450.00'
```

Here's how I'd structure the JavaScript

```
function superSalePrice(discount) {
  var price = $("#productTotal").text();
  price = parseFloat(price.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
  price *= discount;

  return Math.round(100 * price) / 100;
)

$('#tB').click(function() {
  var total = superSalePrice(0.85);
  alert("With selected options, final price with discounts is $" + total + "!");
};
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="tB" value="Test Disc. Calc." />

<td id="productTotal" class="rowElement3">$3,450.00</td>
```

Also, your HTML is invalid. `<td>` and `<input>` elements cannot be siblings.

Comment: I don't think the input and td elements are siblings, the OP just put them in the question for our information. Good point though :)

Comment: And I was just wondering - what is the second parameter for `parseFloat` used for? I've seen that a lot lately but can't find documentation for what two parameters can do.

Comment: It's the radix. You can convert strings to any base, but I like to specify base verbosely `10`.

Comment: Thank you for your time in responding!

Comment: @ianpgall: My mistake. Only `parseInt` takes the radix. `parseFloat` does not.

Comment: Oooh okay, I don't know why I didn't check `parseInt` documentation...I see that now. Thanks for explaining :)